# iOS-FBConnect - requests results crash the app if the delegate of them released

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, facebook, fbconnect

I'm developing an iOS app and views create a request for their data,
now if the user dismiss the view, it's released and when the FBConnect call:

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:
      @selector(request:didReceiveResponse:)]) {
    [_delegate request:self didReceiveResponse:httpResponse];
  }
```

the app is crashed...

Any solution for that case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a higher-level controller as delegate, e.g. the main view controller, or the app delegate itself. This way you will always be sure that that component will not be released while the app is running.

Answer (score 1):

either retain the _delegate. Or release the caller (the one making requests) as well from _delegate's dealloc method.

Or if both the above solutions are not suitable, then put the protocol implementation somewhere else.If you post more details may be then people will be able to provide specific answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't retain the _delegate (every cell in a table view opens that view that sends request) and if the user clicks back button the view and it's objects are released of course. And I think it'll be problematic to transfer FBConnect code to somewhere else in my code. Any other option?

Comment: Try what I suggested in my answer. Use an "always alive" object as a delegate.